# How to add "final sale" next to special price in cart page magento

Tags: php, magento

I would like to add "final sale" for sale items next to special price in cart page.
i added

```
<span class="price-label"><?php  echo $this->__('Final Sale')  ?></span>
```

in 
`template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` 
but I am getting final sale for all the items in cart page.
i want to add final sale for only sales items.
How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually do this with an observer. The event to use is `core_block_abstract_to_html_after` and then you you can get that block's html with:

```
  $transport = $observer->getTransport();
  $html = $transport->getHtml();

  // do some stuff here to determine which items you need to edit the label for.
  // after editing the label, maybe with DomDocument and xpath, set the new html at the end 
  // of your observer like so:

  $transport->setHtml($html);
```

I use this method all the time because i hate modifying template files when the change is something small like you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Transate Inline.

Turn it on via System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Translate Inline.

You can change what it says by clicking it and changing the words to "Final Sale".

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer, it didn't solve my problem.i want to add FINAL SALE for only sale items in cart page.